# Combobox set Default Value

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a form that contains a combobox with a list of employees. I want to set the last selected as default value for this combobox when it open next time. Below it is following my code that isn't working.

```
    Private Sub combobox_AfterUpdate()
    newDefault = Form_Calc.combobox.Text
    Form_Calc.combobox.DefaultValue = newDefault
    End Sub
```

The list contains complete names,  something like: "John Snow";"Mary Jane Johnson";"etc"

Anyone?

Comment: Try the following : 

    Form_Calc!combobox.DefaultValue = Me!Product.ItemData(0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Text` property is only available while the combo has focus.  At any other time you must use its `.Value` property.

This works with my combo box and does what I think you're asking for.

```vb
Private Sub cboAccountID_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboAccountID.DefaultValue = Me.cboAccountID.Value
    MsgBox "DefaultValue: " & Me.cboAccountID.DefaultValue
End Sub
```

That approach will maintain the DefaultValue as you wish until you close the form.  But you want to use the last value again when the form is opened next time.

In that case, you can save the value at `Form_Close` and restore it next time in `Form_Load`.

I use a table to store user option values.  And I have this query, *qryUpdateOption*, to update a saved value.

```sql
PARAMETERS pKey Text ( 255 ), pValue Text ( 255 );
UPDATE tblOptions AS o
SET o.option_value = [pValue]
WHERE o.option_key=[pKey];
```

So at `Form_Close`, I can save the current value of `cboAccountID.DefaultValue`.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = currentd
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryUpdateOption")
qdf.Parameters("pValue").value = Me.cboAccountID.DefaultValue
qdf.Parameters("pKey").value = "cboAccountID.DefaultValue"
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

And at `Form_Load`, I can retrieve that value and assign it to `cboAccountID.DefaultValue`.

```vb
Me.cboAccountID.DefaultValue = DLookup("option_value", _
    "tblOptions", "option_key='cboAccountID.DefaultValue'")
```

Note this suggestion assumes a row exists in *tblOptions* with the *"cboAccountID.DefaultValue"* key.  You may want to refine this outlined suggestion.

And I think it could work for you since each of your users has their own db file which contains both the form and data ... you don't need to be concerned about one user over-writing another user's saved preference.

Comment: I already tried this. While the form is open the default value is that selected, but when closed and opened again there's no default value.

Comment: If you want the `DefaultValue` change to persist, you must save it in  the form's design.

Comment: How do I do this dynamically? The ideia is that each time that the last user change the selected value this become the default value.

Comment: I think we need more details.  Do all the users open the same db file, or does each user have their own copy of a front-end db file, with the shared data stored in a back-end db file?

Comment: Each user has a local mdb, and the tables are local. But this combobox uses a list, not a table.

Comment: Now I'm more confused.  If each user has their own db file which contains both the form and data, how can you change the combo default value for the next user based on the last user's activity.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, we have some laptops, and these laptops are used by different people in different days. Each laptop has a local mdb.   :D

Comment: I'll create a table that register the last person that used the form, and then when the form'll be opened get the last person added. Thanks.